# Читает строки из файла через раз

Tags: c++, строки, getline

Проблема такая: есть файл, где данные записаны сплошным столбиком. Сначала имя, потом возраст. Данный кусок кода должен это всё дело считать с файла и записать в массив, с чем он справляется, но не так, как было задумано автором. Непонятно откуда берётся строка без текста и с 0. Если ввести размер не 3, а 5, то выводит что нужно, но с этими пустыми. Как я понял, оно их берёт из неоткуда и учитывает. Код функции ниже.Прошу, помогите!!!!!!

```
struct slist* getListfromFile(struct slist*& aol, string path, int size)
{
    path = getFilePath();
    fstream ListFile(path, fstream::in);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        getline(ListFile, aol[i].name);
        ListFile >> aol[i].score;
        ListFile.clear();
    }
    ListFile.close();
    return aol;
}
```

*картинка с файлом*

[image] [image: а вот что в консоли]

Comment: "**ИЗ** файла" годдэмит! "н**И**откуда"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После считывания числа из файла

```
ListFile >> aol[i].score;
```

перевод строки остаётся не прочитанным, и будет прочитан на следующей итерации цикла гетлайном. После считывания числа просто игнорируй остаток строки

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    getline(ListFile, aol[i].name);
    ListFile >> aol[i].score;
    ListFile.clear();
    ListFile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Пример на [https://ideone.com/](https://ideone.com/Smk8fV)